# Reading JSON with id outside curly brackets and no quotation marks

Tags: r, json, import, notepad++

I am having some troubles importing a json file to R with the following format:

```
C135-HR2459 {"number_a": 1, "number_b":2} 
C156-HR2249 {"number_a": 1, "number_b":2}
```

It would have worked if it had the following format:

```
{"id": C135-HR2459, "number_a": 1, "number_b":2} 
{"id": C156-HR2249, "number_a": 1, "number_b":2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Notepad++, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\S+) {`
- Replace with: `{"id": "$1",`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(\S+)       # group 1, 1 or more non space character; you can use (.+?) if the string contains spaces
            # 1 space
{           # open curly brace
```

**Replacement:**

```
{"id": "    # literally
$1          # content of group 1
",          # literally, there is a space after the comma
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read it in as pure text with `readLines` and then massage it with regex before try to read as JSON.

First remove the misplaced `"{"` and then add `'{"id: "'` to the beginning of each element:

```
sub("^", "{id: ", sub("\\{", "", txt))
[1] "{id: C135-HR2459\t\"number_a\": 1, \"number_b\":2}" "{id: C156-HR2249\t\"number_a\": 1, \"number_b\":2}"
```

The elimination of the interior `"{"` is done by the "inner `sub`. R functions need to be read and understood from the inside to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

using regex you can search for this:

```
C(.*?)\-HR(.*?) \{(.*?)\}
```

and replace it with this:

```
\{\"id\"\:\"C\1\-HR\2\", \3 \}
```

Be aware that the result will be :

```
{"id":"C135-HR2459", "number_a": 1, "number_b":2 } 
{"id":"C156-HR2249", "number_a": 1, "number_b":2 }
```

where

the value for the id MUST be between "" since is a string

also this here:

```
{"id": C135-HR2459, "number_a": 1, "number_b":2} 
{"id": C156-HR2249, "number_a": 1, "number_b":2}
```

is not a valid json, because the id value is not between quotes